# Component not maintaining input state after checkbox is checked within the table

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement Table component what has text field, on submit it should validate the empty fields. If the checkbox is checked, then don't validate that row. But here on checkbox unchecked text field loses its previous value.

May be I am doing something wrong with my code, don't know why it is behaving like this.
For a reference I am attaching recorded evidence.

[image]

My code

```
interface InconsistenciesTableProps {
  inconsistencies: Inconsistency[] | null;
  onSubmit: (value: InconsistencyRequestData) => void;
}

const InconsistenciesTable = ({inconsistencies,onSubmit}: InconsistenciesTableProps) => {
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<RowSelectionState>()
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowError(false)
    
    if(selectedRows) {
      selectedRows?.forEach(row => {
        updateInconsistencies(row,'status','success')
      })

      const inconsistenciesIds = inconsistencies?.map(data => {return data.id})
      const unSelectedRows = inconsistenciesIds?.filter(id => !Array.from(selectedRows).includes(id))
      unSelectedRows?.forEach(row => {
        updateInconsistencies(row,'status','invalid')
      })
    }
  },[selectedRows])

  const updateInconsistencies = (id: string, key: string, value: string) => {
    const inconsistencyIndex = inconsistencies?.findIndex(data => data.id === id)
    inconsistencies[inconsistencyIndex] = {
      ...inconsistencies[inconsistencyIndex],
      [key]: value
    }
  }

  const explanation = (id: string, val: string) => {
    updateInconsistencies(id,'explanation',val)
  }

  const checkHasError = (inconsistency: Inconsistency) => {
    return showError && inconsistency.status === 'invalid' && inconsistency.explanation === ''
  }
  
  const tableBody = (inconsistencies: Inconsistency[]): TableRows[] => {
    return inconsistencies?.map(inconsistency => {
      const tableCells: TableCells[] = [
        {
          id: 'quantity_'+inconsistency.id,
          content: inconsistency.quantity
        },
        {
          id: 'explanation_'+inconsistency.id,
          content: <ExplanationForm 
            isVisible={!selectedRows?.has(inconsistency.id)} 
            value={inconsistency.explanation || ''} 
            onChange={val => explanation(inconsistency.id,val)} 
            hasError={checkHasError(inconsistency)}
          />
        }
      ]
      return {
        id: inconsistency.id,
        content: tableCells
      }
    })
  }

  const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    setShowError(true)
    const isInconsistency = validityComparison()
    
    if(!isInconsistency) {
      selectedRows?.forEach(row => {
        updateInconsistencies(row,'explanation','')
      })
      const requestData: InconsistencyRequestData = {
        inconsistencies: inconsistencies
      }
      onSubmit(requestData)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {inconsistencies &&
        <Table 
          content={tableBody(inconsistencies)} 
          onRowSelectionChange={setSelectedRows}
          state={{rowSelection: selectedRows || new Set()}}
        />
      }
      <Button className="uppercase" text="CONFIRM AND SEND" onClick={handleOnSubmit} />
    </>
  )
}

export default InconsistenciesTable
```

Update:
Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-paper-0hpgff?file=/src/App.tsx

In a sandbox its working fine, but not working on my local machine.
If there is any area of improvements, then let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I have re-written the code from scratch and now I understood where the problem is. It's in the form field where I am using inside the Table.

I have updated the sandbox code and it is giving another error now.
New sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-ptolemy-1hqhm8

Comment: i suggest you provide a codesandbox so others can help you better

Comment: yeah a live demo or more code is needed to provide an answer, but make sure you have no nested component declarations otherwise your going behind reacts state management. I only say this because `tableBody` looks like its rendering UI and its within `InconsistenciesTable`'s declaration, meaning you are remounting `tableBody`  on every render of `InconsistenciesTable`

Comment: @VinXi I have added sandbox url above.

Comment: If it is working fine in sandbox, then we have nothing to solve, please see what is the difference in code between your local machine and sandbox

Comment: @VinXi I have added new sandbox link, can tell me where I am wrong?